# How to kill several processes in java?

Tags: java, process, runtime, kill

I want to create some processes, then kill one after another (waiting 2 seconds before each kill). As a result, 3 windows should appear and then disappear in order. The problem is only the first process is killed.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");
        Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("calc.exe");
        Process p3 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "start", "dir"});
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        // p1.waitFor(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        p1.destroy();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //  p2.waitFor(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        p2.destroy();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //  p3.waitFor(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        p3.destroy();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("" + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: (3) starts a sub-process. The started process will exit of its own accord and doesn't need killing at all. Rather a pointless example.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **Java 9**, you can use [ProcessHandle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html) and [destroyForcibibly()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html#destroyForcibly--) method which is almost the same as `kill -9`, but since **Java 8** u could use `destroyForcibly()` on `Process` object.

**@Edit**

It's problem only with calc.exe and cmd.exe, so let have a look to `calc.exe` process.

When you run `calc.exe`, `calc.exe` starts `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1804.911.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe`

So these process are different.`Calc.exe` starts another process with other PID.

**What to do?**

On **Java 9**, You can use `ProcessHandle` class to find process which are run from this dir, take PID and kill:

I get:
`Optional[C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1804.911.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Calculator.exe]`

To get our process, you can get snapshot of process before start calc.exe, and compare to snapshot after run calc.exe. But this is not 100% sure that you get only one calculator.exe.

It can be like that, user and your App start calc.exe in the same time. So you get two Process of `Calc.exe`, one start by you and one by app.

Comment: I tried `p1.destroyForcibly(); p2.destroyForcibly()`... , but only first one is killed.I want all them killed one by one... My Java is **Java 8.2**